# Dependency property and TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have wierd problem and I don't know completely what is going on. In my windows phone 8 application I created user control with dependency property:

```
public string Symbol
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SymbolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SymbolProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbolProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Symbol", typeof(string), typeof(SymbolControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    public SymbolControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

view of user control:

```
<Grid x:Name="SymbolRoot" Background="DarkBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Symbol}" Grid.Row="1" Background="Azure" />
</Grid>
```

And now in my view of application I've created

```
<customControls:SymbolControl Symbol="test" />
```

The application always throws TypeInitializationException from setter of symbol.I can't find solution for that or mistake in my code. Can someone help me ?

Stack trace:

> at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(Boolean fIsAttachedDP,
>   String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata
>   propertyMetadata, Boolean readOnly)  at
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, Type
>   propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata)  at
>   Application.WP8.Controls.Symbol.SymbolControl..cctor()

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: "Default value type does not match type of property."

Comment: Just a thought, change `PropertyMetadata("")` to either `PropertyMetadata(null)` or `PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)` and give it a shot.

Comment: It didn't help. What's more if I changed <customControls:SymbolControl  Symbol="test"/> to <customControls:SymbolControl />  in my view there is no exception.

Comment: Post the stack trace please

Comment: Restarting visual or creating new user control was solution. Thanks everyone for help.